# Force correct onActivityResult method call - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a Fragment which loads a DialogFragment.  The DialogFragment that is loaded is a pop-over style that allows the user to choose a photo or take one from their camera.  I have a onActivityResult method in my DialogFragment class, which I want to be called when they have taken the photo or selected it from the Gallery.

The problem is, I also have an onActivityResult in the parent Fragment.  I added it so I can set the target fragment when creating the dialog and then get a callback when the dialog is closed so I know to perform additional actions.

I use this to show the DialogFragment from within my main fragment...

```
DialogFragment profilePhotoChoose = new ProfilePhotoChoose();
profilePhotoChoose.setShowsDialog(true);
profilePhotoChoose.setCancelable(false);
profilePhotoChoose.setTargetFragment(MyMainFragment.this, REQUEST_CODE); // request code is simply int value
profilePhotoChoose.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogPhotoChoose");
```

What happens is, the onActivityResult method of the main fragment gets triggered, instead of the onActivityResult of the dialogfragment.

How can I ensure it calls the correct one?  Do I need to add something to the intent that triggers the camera or gallery?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I use for starting my camera intent from within the DialogFragment.  Please note, I'm using the support DialogFragment.

```
Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null){
                    try {
                        File file = .... // file stuff here
                        if (file != null) {
                            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),"com.MYAPPID.android.provider", file);
                            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: I just realized that your question was to forward only certain requests to your fragment, I edited my question a bit, I believe you can add a check for `requestCode` in your Activity `onActivityResult` before redirecting it to a certain fragment, for example if a `requestCode` is 1 then go to parent fragment and if it's 2 then go to child fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the event is received in the **Activity** first, you need to then redirect it to your **Fragment**, so in your **Activity**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment yourChildFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG");
    yourChildFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

That should invoke your **Fragment's** `onActivityResult`. If you want to forward it to a specific call you may try to add a requestCode check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use onActivityResult() in DialogFragment instead you can check for request code in main fragment onActivityResult() method like
Start You intent like this:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and in onActivityResult() method check for request code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the onActivityResult in the DialogFragment to modify elements within the dialog itself, so I need it there.  I just need the one in my parent fragment to only be called when the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: can you please share your code for starting intent in dialog fragment and onActivityResult of dialogfragment?